# Integral: Gaussian with $\arccos(1/1+x)$ in the exponent...

Tags: calculus, integration

I need some help evaluating this:

$$\int e^{\beta\arccos(a/(a+x))}dx$$

I think its trickier than it looks....

Comment: are $\beta$ and $a$ constant?

Comment: Looks like it involves a hypergeometric.

Comment: yes, they are constants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is too complicated to be shown step by step. The solution includes hypergeometric functions. The easiest way of solving it is to use wolframalpha